# R : Define a variable as 1, each time a condition is met the first time

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr

Trying to set up a new variable for my dataset. It´s supposed to take on the value "1", everytime one of the other variables within the defined group takes on the value 0 for the first time. In the other cases, so e.g. the other variables taking on 0 for the second, third time and so on or being one, the new variable should be 0.

So it should look something like this:

```
ID   Var1   Var2  VarNew
1     1      1      0
1     1      1      0
1     0      1      1
1     0      1      0
1     0      0      1
2     1      1      0
2     1      1      0
2     1      1      0
2     0      1      1
2     0      1      0
```

i tried writing a function and using `ifelse()`, but it did not work.
Could anyone help me with this task? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is _the defined group_? Is this related to `ID`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way. It calls `ave` for each vector `Var*` and then combines the two results.

```
new1 <- with(df1, ave(Var1, ID, FUN = function(x) cumsum(x == 0) == 1))
new2 <- with(df1, ave(Var2, ID, FUN = function(x) cumsum(x == 0) == 1))
df1$VarNew2 <- +(new1 + new2 > 0)

identical(df1$VarNew, df1$VarNew2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Final clean-up.

```
rm(new1, new2)
```

---

Another way, maybe simpler, is to `sapply` `ave` to each of the `Var*` columns.

```
tmp <- sapply(df1[c('Var1', 'Var2')], function(x){
  ave(x, df1$ID, FUN = function(y) cumsum(y == 0) == 1)
})
df1$VarNew2 <- rowSums(tmp > 0)
```

But in this case, the new column is of class `"numeric"`, whereas `"VarNew"` is integer as can be seen with `str`. This causes `identical` to return `FALSE`. But `all.equal` returns `TRUE`, since the numeric values are equal.

```
str(df1)
#'data.frame':  10 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ ID     : int  1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
# $ Var1   : int  1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
# $ Var2   : int  1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
# $ VarNew : int  0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
# $ VarNew2: num  0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0

all.equal(df1$VarNew, df1$VarNew2)
#[1] TRUE

rm(tmp)
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
ID   Var1   Var2  VarNew
1     1      1      0
1     1      1      0
1     0      1      1
1     0      1      0
1     0      0      1
2     1      1      0
2     1      1      0
2     1      1      0
2     0      1      1
2     0      1      0
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @rui barrabas. however it returns a new column contiáining a row of zeros and ones that dont follow the pattern they should. Just a bunch of numbers. Does this have something to do with the fact that I have more than two columns in the actual dataset?

Comment: @philipp.kn_98 With the posted data this solution works. Can you post sample data where it fails?